# PGI Fortran error: PGF90-S-0155-IGNORE_TKR may not be specified for str (npy.f90)

Tags: fortran, gfortran, pgi

I am saving a 2D array into a python numpy .npy format using [npy_for_fortran](https://github.com/MRedies/NPY-for-Fortran). I copy a npy.f90 file into the present directory, add a line `use m_npy` in the beginning and `call save_npy(filename_str,array)` to save the fortran `array` in `.npy` format.

I compile using the following commands in Ubuntu OS bash terminal as explained [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Compiling+and+linking+modules)

```
gfortran -ffree-form -c npy.f90 my_code.f
gfortran npy.o my_code.o -o a.out
```

And I run `a.out`.

Now, how to do the same thing with [PGI's pgfortran](https://www.pgroup.com/products/community.htm)?
If I just replace `gfortran` with `pgfortran` and flag `-ffree-form` with `-Mfree`, I don't get any `.o` files and don't get any `a.out` files either.

Can anyone help me how to do the same with `pgfortran`?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** output messages

```
happy@pop-os:~/Desktop/tmp$ pgfortran -v -Mfree -c npy.f90 mycode.f
Export PGI_CURR_CUDA_HOME=/home/happy/my_bin/linux86-64-llvm/2019/cuda/
Export PGI=/home/happy/my_bin
npy.f90:

/home/happy/my_bin/linux86-64-llvm/19.10/bin/pgf901-llvm npy.f90 -opt 1 -nostatic -x 19 0x400000 -quad -x 59 4 -x 15 2 -x 49 0x400004 -x 51 0x20 -x 57 0x4c -x 58 0x10000 -x 124 0x1000 -tp haswell -x 57 0xfb0000 -x 58 0x78031040 -x 47 0x08 -x 48 4608 -x 49 0x100 -stdinc /home/happy/my_bin/linux86-64-llvm/19.10/include-gcc70:/home/happy/my_bin/linux86-64-llvm/19.10/include:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include:/usr/local/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/include -cmdline '+pgfortran npy.f90 -v -Mfree -c' -def unix -def __unix -def __unix__ -def linux -def __linux -def __linux__ -def __NO_MATH_INLINES -def __LP64__ -def __x86_64 -def __x86_64__ -def __LONG_MAX__=9223372036854775807L -def '__SIZE_TYPE__=unsigned long int' -def '__PTRDIFF_TYPE__=long int' -def __amd64 -def __amd64__ -def __k8 -def __k8__ -def __MMX__ -def __SSE__ -def __SSE2__ -def __SSE3__ -def __SSSE3__ -def __PGLLVM__ -def __extension__= -freeform -vect 48 -x 54 1 -x 70 0x40000000 -x 195 0x8000 -x 70 0x40000000 -x 68 0x1 -y 163 0xc0000000 -x 189 0x10 -freeform -stbfile /tmp/pgfortranB7GGrMytczLF.stb -modexport /tmp/pgfortranZ7GGzy9hSI0F.cmod -modindex /tmp/pgfortranl7GGHBiTp5v_.cmdx -output /tmp/pgfortrand7GGj9WNwCEi.ilm
  0 inform,   0 warnings,   0 severes, 0 fatal for m_npy
PGF90-S-0155-IGNORE_TKR may not be specified for str (npy.f90)
  0 inform,   0 warnings,   1 severes, 0 fatal for dict_str
PGF90-S-0155-IGNORE_TKR may not be specified for str (npy.f90)
PGF90-S-0155-IGNORE_TKR may not be specified for fin_str (npy.f90)
  0 inform,   0 warnings,   2 severes, 0 fatal for shape_str
PGF90/x86-64 Linux 19.10-0: compilation completed with severe errors
pgfortran-Fatal-f901 completed with exit code 1

mycode.f:

/home/happy/my_bin/linux86-64-llvm/19.10/bin/pgf901-llvm mycode.f -opt 1 -nostatic -x 19 0x400000 -quad -x 59 4 -x 15 2 -x 49 0x400004 -x 51 0x20 -x 57 0x4c -x 58 0x10000 -x 124 0x1000 -tp haswell -x 57 0xfb0000 -x 58 0x78031040 -x 47 0x08 -x 48 4608 -x 49 0x100 -stdinc /home/happy/my_bin/linux86-64-llvm/19.10/include-gcc70:/home/happy/my_bin/linux86-64-llvm/19.10/include:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include:/usr/local/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/include -cmdline '+pgfortran mycode.f -v -Mfree -c' -def unix -def __unix -def __unix__ -def linux -def __linux -def __linux__ -def __NO_MATH_INLINES -def __LP64__ -def __x86_64 -def __x86_64__ -def __LONG_MAX__=9223372036854775807L -def '__SIZE_TYPE__=unsigned long int' -def '__PTRDIFF_TYPE__=long int' -def __amd64 -def __amd64__ -def __k8 -def __k8__ -def __MMX__ -def __SSE__ -def __SSE2__ -def __SSE3__ -def __SSSE3__ -def __PGLLVM__ -def __extension__= -nofreeform -vect 48 -x 54 1 -x 70 0x40000000 -x 195 0x8000 -x 70 0x40000000 -x 68 0x1 -y 163 0xc0000000 -x 189 0x10 -freeform -stbfile /tmp/pgfortran77GGX0Qc9YSv.stb -modexport /tmp/pgfortrant7GG5AHHUZit.cmod -modindex /tmp/pgfortranR7GGbYmdj1kO.cmdx -output /tmp/pgfortranJ7GGP3RNrkVW.ilm
PGF90-S-0155-IGNORE_TKR may not be specified for str (mycode.f)
PGF90-S-0155-IGNORE_TKR may not be specified for fin_str (mycode.f)
  0 inform,   0 warnings,   2 severes, 0 fatal for julia_set_complex_polinomial
PGF90/x86-64 Linux 19.10-0: compilation completed with severe errors
pgfortran-Fatal-f901 completed with exit code 1

Unlinking /tmp/pgfortrand7GGj9WNwCEi.ilm
Unlinking /tmp/pgfortranB7GGrMytczLF.stb
Unlinking /tmp/pgfortranZ7GGzy9hSI0F.cmod
Unlinking /tmp/pgfortranl7GGHBiTp5v_.cmdx
Unlinking /tmp/pgfortranJ7GGP3RNrkVW.ilm
Unlinking /tmp/pgfortran77GGX0Qc9YSv.stb
Unlinking /tmp/pgfortrant7GG5AHHUZit.cmod
Unlinking /tmp/pgfortranR7GGbYmdj1kO.cmdx
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full command line and output from the compilation and link as well as adding the "-v" (verbose) flag?  Hopefully this gives a bit more detail to determine the issue.

Comment: The output is too long and can fit in the comment. `pgfortran -v -Mfree -c npy.f90 mycode.f` produeces only `m_npy.mod`. gfortran used to produce `npy.o` and `mycode.o` as well. There are few severes in output.

Comment: So the issue is that you're getting a severe error?  That would prevent an object file from being generated.  What's the error?  Can you post the full output from the compile though without the "-v" flag?  Note that it's best if you edit your original post with the updated information.  The more detailed information that you can provide, the easier it will be for folks to help you.

Comment: I edited the post with the output messages.

Answer (score 1):

The title is misleading in that the method being used to compile and link is fine.  The actual error is because the code being compiled is using a new Fortran feature, assumed rank, that PGI doesn't yet support.  You either need to only use gfortran for this project, or update the source to not use assume ranks.

Comment: "only use gfortran" may be replaced by "use a compiler which supports assumed rank" or there is something else which makes this specific to gfortran?

Comment: Since the OP was using gfortran, I suggested he use it.  But you are correct in that if other compilers support assumed rank, he should be able to use it as well.  Note that PGI's (recently re-branded as NVIDIA's HPC Compiler) path forward for adding new Fortran features is through the Flang F18 project which we're developing with community involvement.  (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/master/flang/)